# Odd behavior (bug?) of sed when using $

Tags: sed, regular-expression, replace, pattern-matching

I've got a problem and I am not sure whether this is a bug or if this is supposed to happen when using $ for addressing lines. Basically, I have the following command:

```
sed -e '$s/test/tset/g'
```

Usually, I would expect it to run like this:

```
blahblah
blahblah
  <-- Cursor is here now
```

Meaning: I type in something and press Enter one time, and the result is shown in the next line, However, instead I get the following:

```
blahblah

blahblah
  <-- Cursor is here now.
```

So, basically the $-symbol seems to somehow cause sed to set the cursor to an empty line and only after I press enter again, it actually shows the result (means: I have to press Enter two times). Is there any way to prevent that or is this possibly a bug? In my more complex patterns this is actually messing up a lot of stuff.

Comment: It has no way to know whether this is the last line until either the input ends or it gets a subsequent line. What are you expecting the command to do (aside from the cursor positioning)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `sed` knows it will have to apply a command to the final line of input, it can't output the most recently processed line until it's sure it can read *more* lines after that.

You would not see the same behaviour in a `sed` editing script *not* using the `$` address, as the transformation of the data does not depend on whether the current line is the final line of input or not.